# Using an existing python3 install with anaconda/miniconda

Tags: python, homebrew, anaconda, miniconda, homebrew-cask

With `python3` previously installed via `homebrew` on macOS, I just downloaded `miniconda` (via `homebrew cask`), which brought in another full python setup, I believe.

Is it possible to install anaconda/miniconda **without** reinstalling python?
And, if so, would that be a bad idea?

Comment: _And, if so, would that be a bad idea?_ Most likely, yes. I can't think of any advantages, only ways that it could go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda comes with python for you but do not remove the original python that comes with the system -- many of the operating system's libs depend on it.

Anaconda manages its python executable and packages in its own (conda) directory. It changes the system path so the python inside the conda directory is the one used when you access python.

Comment: Right, I was just wondering if it's absolutely necessary for Anaconda to use its own copy of python, as opposed to pointing to an already existing version...